# Как узнать, кто пригласил человека на сервер discord JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord

Я писал бота на Java Script, и мен нужно узнать, кто пригласил пользователя на сервер, как это лучше сделать?

Могу сбросить код

Answer (score 1):

Порекомендую [данный](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites#catching-new-members) код:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.fetchInvites().then(guildInvites => {
    const ei = invites[member.guild.id];
    invites[member.guild.id] = guildInvites;
    const invite = guildInvites.find(i => ei.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
    const inviter = client.users.cache.get(invite.inviter.id);
    const logChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "join-logs");
    logChannel.send(`${member.user.tag} joined using invite code ${invite.code} from ${inviter.tag}. Invite was used ${invite.uses} times since its creation.`);
  });
});
```